# "XQuery [nodes()]: The XQuery syntax 'union' is not supported."

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

With the following code below, I am getting the following error:

> XQuery [nodes()]: The XQuery syntax 'union' is not supported.

`DECLARE @input XML =` (I'm trying to type in the full XML for this string, but it's not translating here (getting truncated).  It even truncates if I select pieces of it.  I know it's key to answering the question, but maybe someone can explain the error, and I can investigate this variable string)??

```
CREATE TABLE #Fields 
(F1RowID int identity(1,1),GroupID int,TableID int,FieldName nvarchar(50)
,FieldValue nvarchar(50),OldFieldValue nvarchar(50),ExcludeField bit)

INSERT INTO #Fields (FieldName,FieldValue,TableID,ExcludeField) 
SELECT FieldName = C.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(50)'),   
FieldValue = C.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)')    ,
TableID = 1,ExcludeField = 0 FROM @input.nodes
('/data/CSNPay|CSNHistoryGroup/CSNPay|CSNHistory/*') AS T(C)
```

Comment: Your input isn't relevant -- XQuery in SQL simply doesn't support the `|` (union) operator. I'm not sure if there's an obvious rewrite.

Comment: This is bizarre, because I could've sworn this code was working before.  Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not support XQuery's union operator `|`. If the individual subqueries do not return overlapping results, you don't really need the set-based union-capability anyway: simply put together a sequence. Otherwise, you'll have to deal with duplicates.

```
FROM @input.nodes('(/data/CSNPay, CSNHistoryGroup/CSNPay, CSNHistory/*)') AS T(C)
```

I'm not sure whether this query is actually doing what you expect -- are you sure about the individual paths (some start at the root, some at the current context)?